# Intuition when solving for intersection of two surfaces

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Consider the ellipsoid $x^2 +  5y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and the plane $x+2z=1$. Study their intersection

Now, I can substitute into ellipse,

$$ x = 1-2z$$ and get an equation in $z $ and $y$ which is a circle and if we plug in $ \frac{x-1}{-2}=z$ into the equation, we get equation in $x$ and $y$ which is an ellipse.

Now, what does it mean geometrically when we plug reduce the variables with different variable from plane we plug into the surface?

Comment: Geometrically, the ellipse is the projection of the intersection of these two surfaces onto the $(x,y)-$plane

Comment: Whether you substitute or use an equality as I did in WolframAlpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+%2B++5y%5E2+%2B+z%5E2+%3D+x%2B2z) it appears you get a spheroid.

Comment: By the way, the 3d shape is not an ellipse (which is a 2d shape), but an *ellipsoid*.

Answer (score 2):

The circle and ellipse are the projections onto the $y,z$- and $x,y$-planes, respectively. The projection onto the $x,z$-plane is a line segment along $x=1-2z$.

Here's a view of these projections. First, the shapes viewed at an angle:

$\hskip{3cm}$[image]

Next, looking straight along the axes, you can see the intersections form a circle, a line segment, an ellipse:

$\hskip{3cm}$[image]
$\hskip{1cm}$[image]
$\hskip{1cm}$[image]

Comment: Could you explain the notion of this projection and how it relates to plugging in algebraic equation?

Comment: @Buraian Sure: when you substitute $x=1-2z$, you end up with a system of two equations: $\{x=1-2z, 5y^2+5z^2-4z=0\}$. This system describes the intersection of the plane and the ellipsoid. Now, suppose that we don't care about the value of $x$; then we can ignore $x=1-2z$ for a moment and we're left with just $5y^2+5z^2-4z=0$, which is a a circle. Geometrically speaking, "ignoring $x$" means that we're looking straight along the $x$-axis, and the picture gets flattened to the $y,z$-plane. This flattening is what we call projection; it is like a shadow cast by the object.